# Would you ever use this, or have you ever thought about something like it? (custom Nav Controller for iPhone)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

Here's a little blogpost on the library: http://www.andrewljohnson.com/article/Customizing%20UINavigationControlBar%20-%20Controls%20and%20Images

And here's a link directly to the GitHub repository:
http://github.com/andrewljohnson/NavControlBar/tree/master

I searched SO and the rest of the internets for how best to do this recently, and I decided this was the way!

Comment: Are you trying to do market research, or do you actually have a question?

Comment: I'm not doing market research... the title is the question. Market research would imply I'm selling something.

Comment: Why not just use a custom UIView as the title?

Answer (score 1):

We have something like this for an app we are working on so we can have custom view transitions.

A piece of advice, if you want this to work correctly with view controllers written to work in a normal navigation controller you need to manually invoke their view(Will|Did)(Appear|Disappear): methods at the appropriate times.

Also, in order to make -[UIViewController navigationController] work in the expected way with your navigation controllers you have to do some particularly unsavory things.

Comment: Well, this completely replaces UINavigationController... we don't use that at all.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't change the fact that UIViewController knows about UINavigationController. In other words, you are not just replacing UINavigationController, but imposing new design constraints on any UIViewControllers hosted in your controller. If you want people to use it as a drop in replacement then it should support the standard entry points.